# I want to add the menu "page-scroll-effects-master". It's made up of "jquery"

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

How do I add a menu?

How do I add navbar?

I’ve tried by id in HTML, if `data-hijacking="off"`, it's good. if `data-hijacking="off"`, it's no good. It is necessary to pick up the jQuery. The menu should be added to jQuery.

Here is code and see: https://codyhouse.co/gem/page-scroll-effects

Draw jquery and add the menu.

Comment: you want to add fixed menu on stick to top with this scrolling effect?

Please share codepen let me help you!

Comment: yes, i want to add fixed menu. here is code, you can dowload, https://codyhouse.co/gem/page-scroll-effects

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt *HERE*, noting input and expected output.

Comment: https://codepen.io/jhealey5/pen/QKNWpm

Comment: Please post it **HERE** - click [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/22649305) then `[<>]` snippet editor

Comment: Please post code directly in your question.  Do not use links and/or post in comments.

Comment: ok i am sorry, but I need it very much, Could you help me.

Comment: _Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer. Avoid asking multiple distinct questions at once._

Answer (score 3):

Add div with any id and

```css
#mynav {
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 5;
  left: 0;
  top: 0px;
  height: 80px;
  padding: 0px;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, .9);
  box-shadow: 0 4px 16px rgba(25, 30, 46, .2);
  font-size: 1.3rem;
  font-weight: 700;
  display: block;
  z-index: 10000;
  background: white;
  width: 2000px;
}
```

```html
<div id="mynav">
  i am nav container
</div>
```

apply css

Comment: this is good,thank you, but I need a menu that works with page scroll effects master.